# MoPub MoPubView error

Tags: java, android, xml, mopub

I started using `MoPub,` implemented the `sdk` and tried to display a banner.

**I have an error after trying to display a banner:**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes
at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:96)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getInstance(WebViewDatabase.java:39) etc.
```

**xml file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**android manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.NeverMind.MainClass.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/extra"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.NeverMind.DontFall.android.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please see this https://twittercommunity.com/t/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-for-security-reasons-webview-is-not-allowed-in-privileged-processes/47515/2

Comment: I saw it already, otherwise I wouldn't post here...